# Create and populate multidimensional array representing minesweeper-type grid

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array to contain arrays of cartesian coordinates (x,y) in a multidimensional array of [X,Y] width and height.

This is where I've gotten to so far; I've become hopelessly confused...

```
int[][][] grid = new int[width][][];
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        grid[x] = new int[height][];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
           grid[y] = new int[2][];
        }
    }

    foreach (int[][] coordinate in grid)
    {
        //        
    }
```

For example, I'd like a 3 x 4 grid to be represented by an array as such:

```
{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}
{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}
{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}
{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}
```

etc...

I've scoured the web for a solution in C# (I'm a relative newcomer to OO, unfamiliar with C, C++ etc.) but have so far drawn a blank.

Am I on the right track in the approach I've taken with the creation of the array?
Can anyone offer some tips on how to populate the array with the coordinates, using loops if possible?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=vs.71).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Why would you need to populate an array with coordinates? Surely the indexes of the arrays **are** the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks folks. Matt, you're completely right; sometimes I'm slower than digesting bananas..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of having a multidimensional array, you could create a class to hold the coordinates (and other stuff related to each tile).

For example, it could look like this :

```
public class Tile
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public int Y {get; set;}
    public bool HasMine {get; set;}
    //Etc.
}
```

So instead of having a multidimensional array, you could use a simple `List<Tile>` to hold all your tiles. All you have to do to populate that list is create a new Tile instance for every tiles, like this :

```
List<Tile> tiles = new List<Tile>();

for(int i = 0; i < NB_HORIZONTAL_TILES; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < NB_VERTICAL_TILES; j++)
        tiles.Add(new Tile { X = i; Y = j });
```

To iterate over them, you can simply use a `foreach` statement or some `LINQ`. That would be a more OO way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

assuming `width` and `height` are integers with your width and height:

```
int[,] grid = new int[width,height];
```

Will create a width x height array filled with zeros (because that's the default value for an integer).

The coordinates of the array are the indexes into the array, so you don't need to populate it for that. All you need to do is store whatever data you want to store at which ever location you want to populate:

```
grid[2,1] = 5;    // the cell at {2,1} now contains the number 5
```

Comment: Could you explain what such declaration mean int[,] grid?

Comment: @Marek: The links Patashu gave you explain it pretty well. `int[,]` declares a 2D rectangular array. This is as opposed to `int[][]` which declares a jagged array (which could happen to be rectangular, but doesn't have to be).